# Azure REST API- List vm sizes with premium disk and ephemeral disk support information/filters

Tags: azure, rest

Azure rest api to list azure vm sizes([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachinesizes/list)) doesn't provide any information about the premium disk and ephemeral disk support. It only have following information-

```
{
  "name": "Basic_A0",
  "numberOfCores": 1,
  "osDiskSizeInMB": 1047552,
  "resourceDiskSizeInMB": 20480,
  "memoryInMB": 768,
  "maxDataDiskCount": 1
}
```

Is there any api which provides vm size list, including information about premium and ephemeral disk support in the respective vm size?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's impossible. The REST API can only get the result as it shows in the document you have seen. It cannot get more details. You only can get more information yourself from the VM sizes for [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/sizes) and [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes).